# Implement matlab code in C++?

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix

I have a certain code written in Matlab. I wanted to obtain similar results using a c++ code. I wanted to know whether a c++ library exists  for matrix manipulations? My current Matlab code consists of matrix multiplications,inverse and complements.

Comment: Trying [the search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%2B%2B]+matrix+library) gives you e.g. [Looking for an elegant and efficient C++ matrix library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359608/looking-for-an-elegant-and-efficient-c-matrix-library).

Comment: This question is exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329994/matlab-functions-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are dozens of linear algebra libraries for C++. Here is another one not mentioned in the other links so far:

http://www.alglib.net/

Answer (score 2):

I have used [Newmat](http://www.robertnz.net/nm10.htm) in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would help you, or your company/university have licenses for it but matlabcoder can export your matlab code to c++ without much extra work.
http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/